# VENSIM TREND Function in system dynamics

Tags: vensim

I am trying to understand VENSIM functions like TREND in System Dynamics. Any suggestions? I have tried reading up a few papers but not fully comprehending what i am reading

Comment: Sorry, SE is not really a place to receive primer for coding

Answer (score 1):

John Sterman has an MIT Working Paper that describes the origins of the TREND function. It may be available online.

These two references will also help: 
Sterman, John D. 1987. Expectation Formation in Behavioral Simulation Models. Behavioral Science, 32:190-211. 
Sterman, John D. 2000, Business Dynamics, Boston, MA: McGraw-Hill. Chapter 16.

Also: https://ceprofs.civil.tamu.edu/dford/dnf%20profesional/TipPtAppdxCForecast-SDR.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The TREND function is an approximation for the GROWTH EXPECTATIONS  of a forecaster. This is, given a particular input signal, an adjustment time and an initial idea of what the trend is, this functions has as output the EXPECTED GRADIENT (TREND) of the input signal.

I would suggest that complementary to reading, you should recreate the model suggested in the VENSIM help literature:

```
      TREND(input, average time,initial trend)
```

which is equivalent to the functions:

```
      TREND=ZIDZ(input-avval,average time*ABS(avval))
      avval=INTEG((input-avval)/average time,input/(1+ini*averate time))
```

and where ZIDZ is a function

```
      ZIDZ(A,B)
```

that returns A/B except when B is zero, then it returns 0.

System dynamics is a discipline famously known for giving a false sense of understanding only through reading. Systems have to be experimented with, as one of Jay Forrester's starting premises for de discipline was that our intuition mis-guides us into thinking we understand a system, when most real systems really very quickly behave counter-intuitively.

Answer (score 1):

In his paper *Expectation Formation in Behavioral Simulation Models* [John Sterman](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/54c4/662c46faa1d190d2a4bdc9b9f858d477f3a3.pdf) explain that *the `TREND` function can be thought of as an information processing procedure which takes as input a variable (including its past values) and produces as output a judgment of the current trend in the input variable.  The value of `TREND` is the expected rate of change in the input variable, expressed as a fraction of the input variable per time unit*.

Into the help of [Vensim](https://www.vensim.com/documentation/index.html?fn_trend.htm) and [AnyLogic](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fsd%2Ftrend.html) softwares we read only that `TREND` function provides a trend estimative for variables always positive and that don’t get very close to zero.